# Why does this for loop run for different number of steps?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that shuffles a deck of cards. It takes a list called cards_deck as inputs with 52 string each corresponding to a card value and shuffles the list to give the output list shuffled_deck.

Here's how I implemented it:

```
def shuffle_cards(card_deck):
    card_deck_temp = card_deck
    shuffled_deck = []
  
    for index in range(0,len(card_deck)):
        i = random.randint(0,len(card_deck_temp)-1)
        print(len(card_deck_temp))
        shuffled_deck.append(card_deck_temp[i])
        card_deck_temp.pop(i)
    
    return shuffled_deck
```

The question is: instead of looping the for in the range of 0 to 52, if I loop it as each item in the list as `for index in card_deck`, the loop only runs 26 times instead of 56. But the above code runs 52 times. Cannot figure out why this would happen.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you change the size of card_deck during iteration as in you code card_deck_temp is card_deck. You need to slice (copy) the list if you want to copy it.

```
def shuffle_cards(card_deck):
    card_deck_temp = card_deck[:]
    shuffled_deck = []

    for index in card_deck:
        i = random.randint(0,len(card_deck_temp)-1)
        print(len(card_deck_temp))
        shuffled_deck.append(card_deck_temp[i])
        card_deck_temp.pop(i)
    
    return shuffled_deck
```

For simplicity you cann also just use random.shuffle:

```
shuffled_deck = card_deck[:]
random.shuffle(shuffled_deck)
```

Comment: Does this mean that when I equal card_deck_temp to card_deck normally without the [:] syntax, it does not create a duplicate variable but just references or points to the original? So if I were to manipulate the temp variable then the original will also get similarly altered? 

Also THANKS a lot for this! Reading up more on slice copy.

Comment: Yes, your're right. When you just assign card_deck to card_deck_temp, both variables will refer to the same location in memory. As Python lists are mutable, any changes to card_deck_temp will happen in place and thus also affect card_deck. Check this [link](https://www.codingem.com/python-mutability-explained/) for further information on mutable vs immutable objects in Python.